# Handle all types of errors except one in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a method which might throw `ParserException` with some meaningful description, and throw general `ParserException` on any `StandardError`:

Just as a minimal reproducible example:

```
begin
  item = parseItem(json)

  if !item.id
    raise ParserException.new("id property is missing")
  end

  item
rescue => ex
  raise ParserException.new("exception occurred when tried to parse JSON", ex: ex)
end
```

Now, the problem is that if the `id` property is missing, then the `ParserException` is being caught, wrapped into another `ParserException` and then re-thrown with less meaningful message.

I can fix it by doing this:

```
begin 
  # ...
rescue ParserException
  raise
rescue => ex
  raise ParserException.new("exception occurred when tried to parse JSON", ex: ex)
end
```

But it may look a little ugly. Is there a more laconic way to achieve this? Something like `rescue !ParserException => ex`?

For example, in C# I can do (this may be considered ugly too, but I am asking because of curiosity):

```
try
{
    throw new ParserException("Specific error");
catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is ParserException))
{
    throw new ParserException("Generic error");
}
```

Comment: You proposed working solution (particular `rescue`, followed by sink-all `rescue`) is the idiomatic right way to go. It is not ugly by any mean.

Comment: If the `ParserException` is _yours_ class, you might reimplement its `initialize` function and if `ex` is _already_ a `ParserException` just clone it. Then single `rescue` would do.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thank you for your answer :) Yeah, I was mostly worried about the Ruby idioms, because I am just learning the language. The second idea sounds good too, I will try this.

Comment: When you say the exception is "caught, wrapped, and then re-thrown with a less meaningful message," won't this happen for other types of exceptions as well? Or is that what you really want?

Comment: @arcadeblast77 Oh, yeah, this is what I want to happen to any unexpected exceptions of any other type :) But I want to let my `ParserException`s to pass through with original message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current fix is probably the cleanest way to go, however I you don't want that additional rescue block you can also handle it in your catch-all solution.

```
begin 
  # ...
rescue => ex
  raise if ex.is_a? ParserException
  raise ParserException.new("exception occurred when tried to parse JSON", ex: ex)
end
```